# trying to understand an issue with C pointers, blocks and go to statements

Tags: c

I am trying get a handle on C and Cyclone as I work my way thru Jim Trevor's "[Cyclone: A safe dialect of C](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/cyclone/papers/cyclone-safety.pdf)" for a PL class. Trevor gives this example of an unsafe go-to statement:

```
int z;
{ int x = 0xBAD; goto L; }
{ int *y = &z;
L: *y = 3; // Possible segfault
}
```

Trevor explains the safety issue in the above code as follows:

Many compilers stack allocate
the local variables of a block when it is entered, and
deallocate (pop) the storage when the block exits
(though this is not mandated by the C standard).
If the example is compiled in this way, then when
the program enters the ﬁrst block, space for x is allocated on the stack, and is initialized with the value
0xBAD. The goto jumps into the middle of the second block, directly to the assignment to the contents
of the pointer y. Since y is the ﬁrst (only) variable
declared in the second block, the assignment expects
y to be at the top of the stack. Unfortunately, that’s
exactly where x was allocated, so the program tries
to write to location 0xBAD, probably triggering a
segmentation fault.

I don't understand why the `go to` statement is an issue here. It seems like the issue is unpredictable behavior from the un-initialized pointer Z. At the start of the second block, `int * y` be filled with the address of Z. Z is uninitialized so it would fill `int* y` with the bit pattern on the stack in the area of memory referenced by Z. I don't understand why Trevor's paper implies that Z and X somehow both reference 0xBAD. Wouldn't C create a new stack frame for the first block (as Trevor describes): thus writing 0xBAD to a new frame in memory (and not the location in memory referenced by Z)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why the go to statement is an issue here.

`goto L` bypasses the initialization of `y` (`y` will not be set to `&z`), hence the problem when assigning to who-knows-where-it's-pointing `*y`.

> It seems like the issue is unpredictable behavior from the
>   un-initialized pointer Z

No.  The pointer `&z` is actually valid.  The `int` value `z` is uninitialized, but that does not matter since you never attempt to read it; you're actually trying to overwrite it.

> At the start of the second block, int * y be filled with the address of Z.

That is the point.  `goto L` bypasses that.

> I don't understand why Trevor's paper implies that Z and X somehow both reference 0xBAD

I think Trevor is implying a second potential problem here, though I'm not sure how many compilers, if any, would actually exhibit it.  When leaving the block with `goto`, the stack pointer (e.g. `ESP` on x86) may theoretically not be decremented.  By skipping the initialization of `y`, the stack pointer may not be incremented either.  So if the compiler refers to locals using the stack pointer (instead of a frame pointer, e.g. `EBP` on x86), such a compiler may theoretically mistake `x` for `y`, as if `int* y = 0xBAD` had happened.

Comment: “When leaving the block with goto, the stack pointer (e.g. ESP on x86) may theoretically not be decremented.” If this is what the authors imply, then the authors are wrong. Automatic variables are freed when execution leaves the scope, period (C99 6.2.4:5). If the implementation the authors of the article had in mind does not have this property, this is only telling of the implementation the authors had in mind, not of standard-compliant C compilers.

Comment: Having now looked at the article, the authors do say “Many compilers stack allocate the local variables of a block when it is entered, and deallocate (pop) the storage when the block exits […] If the example is compiled in this way …“. This part is rubbish.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, "this part is rubbish" -- disputable. GCC will do just that on x86 if one of (depending on GCC version) --param=min-pretend-dynamic-size=1, -fstack-reuse=all etc. are provided; in their absence GCC will preallocate the stack frame to accomodate most locals as soon as a method is entered. Whatever do you mean by *freed* in "Automatic variables are *freed* when execution leaves the scope"? The standard has always stopped at saying that dereferencing a pointer to an object after the object's lifetime has ended is "undefined", it never said anything about storage reuse (or no reuse.)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand the problem if you remove the block and separate out the initialization and declaration of the values.

```
int z;
int *y;
goto L;
y = &z;
L: 
*y = 42;
```

This is essentially what is happening in the original sample but a bit clearer.  Here the line `y = &z` is never executed hence `y` is pointing to an undefined location and hence it's set is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the language is concerned, the program's behavior is simply undefined. The `goto` skips the initialization of `y`; the pointer object exists, but it doesn't point to any defined location. Dereferencing `y` has undefined behavior.

But looking at the code in a bit more detail, and making some (unwarranted) assumptions about how it behaves:

```
int z;
{ 
    int x = 0xBAD; goto L; 
}   
{ 
    int *y = &z;
    L: *y = 3; // Possible segfault
}
```

Local variables are (typically) allocated on the stack. Each local variable ceases to exist when control reaches the end of the block that contains its definition.

The idea, I think, is that the first block creates an `int` object `x`, and assigns the value `0xBAD` to it.  `x` ceases to exist when the `goto` transfers control out of that block -- but the `0xBAD` value may still exist just above the top of the stack.

The `goto` transfers control into the second block. It skips the initialization of `y`, but not its allocation; the pointer object `y` is still allocated on the stack, whether control enters the block directly or via a `goto` statement. If the `0xBAD` value was left above the top of the stack, then `y` could easily be allocated in the same location; since the initialization was skipped, the `0xBAD` value could be left in `y` (or rather, the bits making up the `int` representation of `0xBAD` remain in `y` and are interpreted as a pointer value).

So the assignment `*y = 3;` attempts to store the value `3` in memory location `0xBAD`.

That's probably the rationale for defining, initialization, and using the variable `x`: to leave a particular garbage value in the memory occupied by `y`.

But in fact *none* of the behavior I've described here (after the first paragraph) is required by the C standard. Objects in parallel blocks, like the ones in the sample, may or may not be stored in the same memory location. The initialization of `x`, and even its allocation on the stack, could easily be eliminated by an optimizing compiler. And local variables needn't even be allocated on "the stack" (in the sense of a contiguous region of memory managed by a stack pointer); the C standard doesn't even use the word "stack". A contiguous stack is the most natural way to implement the required semantics for local variables, but it's not required. nd of course an `int` and an `int*` needn't be the same size.

Bottom line: When `*y = 3;` is executed, the value of `y` is uninitialized garbage (I'm deliberately avoiding the word "random"), so the behavior of dereferencing `y` is undefined. Given certain assumptions, that garbage *might* happen to look like `0xBAD`, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem is that the variable `y` might be accessed before it's initialized.  The code snippet you gave is just one way that's likely to demonstrate the problem.

When I compile this with GCC with the `-Wall` option, it warns that `warning 'y' is used uninitialized in this function`.  If I compiled it as C++ code with g++, it's actually an error:

```
test.cc:8:3: error: jump to label ‘L’
test.cc:6:25: error:   from here
test.cc:7:10: error:   crosses initialization of ‘int* y’
```

Although in this case `y` is a POD type, if it were instead a class that had a constructor, the `goto` would skip the constructor.  The C++ language specification says this is illegal in all cases.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @Keith: I know, and I answered it for C, but I also thought that it would be informative to show that it's an error in C++.